# 3 Brownian motion and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

I'm supposed to compute

$E\left(W_6 | W_2 , W_4\right)$ knowing that $W$ is a standard Brownian motion.

I found $W_2$ but it's weird... Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

$E(W_6|W_2,W_4)=E(W_6-W_4|W_2,W_4)+E(W_4|W_2,W_4)=E(W_6-W_4)+W_4=0+W_4=W_4$.

For the second inequality I have used independence of $W_6-W_4$ and $(W_2,W_4)$

Comment: Hi ! Why are you doing this with $W_4$ and not $W_2$ for example ?

Comment: $W_6-W_4$ is independent of both $W_2$ and $W_4$ (in fact jointly). But if I had written $W_6$  as $(W_6-W_2) +W_2$ I wouldn't  know that $E(W_6-W_2|W_2,W_4)=E(W_6-W_2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much !